# SSH port open and is allowed in firewall, still not able to login

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-16.04, vmware-vcloud-director

I have an Ubuntu machine in VMWare infrastructure. It has got a public IP address to which I can ping easily. I have installed openssh-server and I can confirm that SSH daemon is running and port 22 is allowed in firewall as well. But still my telnet to port 22 and SSH connection using putty is not connecting to that machine. Any ideas to solve this would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Just did a grep now to see the running process and its showing there:
[image]

Comment: When you say not connecting...are you getting a specific error message or is the connection attempt just timing out? Are you able to SSH from the local console back to the localhost address `ssh username@127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. vCloud Director has a setting of DNAT whereby redirecting public IP to required server's private IP with port number. Changed that to my server private IP and started working fine. This setting was unknown to me till now.Thought of posting this answer, maybe someone will find helpful.